# Relacionar colecciones en firebase

Tags: firebase

Una pregunto como hago para pedir datos de dos coleciones mediante una consulta en firebase, por ejemplo, tengo una colecion cita y otra paciente, y quisiera obtener el nombre del paciente de dicha cita. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, ¿has intentado algo por tu cuenta? Si es así, puedes compartirlo para ver cómo podemos ayudarte y ver si la dirección que has tomado es correcta o ayudarte a corregir el rumbo. Saludos

Comment: query1() {
      db.collection("Pacientes").where("nombres", "==", "cristian").get()
      
    }                                                                                                                            trate de hacer esta consultas pero no me da resultados aún, no estoy seguro de que este bien planteado

Comment: Hola, disculpa por ser tan meticuloso. Edita tu pregunta y agregas esa información que pones en el comentario. Sería bueno que pudieras aclarar cómo relacionas tu colección `pacientes` con la colección `citas`. Todo en al área de la pregunta. Así será mejor recibida y tienes más posibilidades de recibir respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Tenía un problema similar, lo que hice para resolverlo fue guardar en la colección, en tu caso paciente, con un idCitaUnico y a la coleccion cita le asigne el mismo idCitaUnico de ese paciente, entonces cuando haces la consulta, llamas al paciente con determinado id, y cuando obtienes ese paciente con el idCita unico, lo guardas en una variable y ejecutas otra funcion pasandole esa variable que acabas de guardar con el idCitaUnico. No se cuan viable será esta solución, en terminos de rendimiento, pero en su momento fue lo unico que se me ocurrio y asi pude resolver el problema

Comment: Se mas especifico en tu respuesta ya que ahora es confusa, te recomiendo leer [¿Como responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)